# Number of divisors of a number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, factoring

Is there any trick to find the number of divisors of any number? For e.g., a quick way to tell the number of divisors of 987655432 (chosen randomly)?

**EDIT:** And it has to be done without prime factorization.

Comment: Get the prime factorisation. If $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$, then the number of divisors of $n$is $\prod (k_i+1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have edited the question now.

Comment: Can you give more information about the motivation for this question? Why is it that you need a way to do this without prime factorization? What leads you to believe/hope that there is such a way?

Comment: There is at least [a name for this divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), $d(n) = \sigma_0(n)$, the number of (positive) divisors of $n \ge 1$. It corresponds to one of [the early OEIS sequences](https://oeis.org/A000005).

Answer (score 4):

Consider the natural number $987655432$. Using prime factorization (and hating our lives while using it, lol) we see that $987655432=2^3\cdot 1033\cdot 119513$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, each factor is of the form $2^a\cdot 1033^b\cdot 119513^c$ where $0\leq a \leq 3$, $0\leq b\leq 1$, and $0\leq c \leq 1$. We see that there are $4$ choices for $a$, $2$ choices for $b$, and $2$ choices for $c$. By the Multiplication principle, the number of factors is $4\cdot 2 \cdot 2=16$.